# When I run the program by stepping in using breakpoints, it executes fine, but when I run it without breakpoints, it gives run time exceptions

Tags: .net, ado.net, entity-framework-4, oledb, visual-studio-debugging

I have a WPF application in which I am reading an Excel file using Microsoft Jet Oledb driver. There are a total of three excel files being read and inserted into the database after applying necessary type conversions.

When I set breakpoints and debug it step by step, I get not exceptions and data is correctly inserted into the DB.

But when I execute it without breakpoints and do not debug, then it gives me the following run time error:

> "Input string was not in a correct
>   format"

Please help me. Why is this happening ?

UPDATE:

> Stack Trace is:    at
>   System.Number.ParseDouble(String
>   value, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberFormatInfo numfmt)    at
>   System.String.System.IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider
>   provider)    at
>   System.Convert.ToDouble(Object value) 
>   at
>   Expedia.MainWindow.InsertCallProfile(DataTable
>   dt) in
>   D:\expedia\Expedia\Expedia\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
>   90    at
>   Expedia.MainWindow.Button_Click(Object
>   sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in
>   D:\expedia\Expedia\Expedia\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
>   44

I knew that there is a Type Conversion problem, but it does not occurr when I set breakpoints and debug.

I am using following for converting data types:-

```
public static Nullable<T> ToNullable<T>(this object o) where T : struct
    {
        Nullable<T> result = new Nullable<T>();
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.ToString()))
            {
                TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
                result = (T)conv.ConvertFrom(o);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add more info about the exception? a stacktrace?

Comment: I am getting a random behaviour, sometimes data is inserted and sometimes I get "Input string was not in a correct format". Please help.

Comment: Try commenting the try/catch-block to see (a) if that function method is even causing an exception and if yes, (b) get more/better information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not something strange if you know how to debug .NET crash in this way,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/03/20/debugging-a-net-crash-with-rules-in-debug-diag.aspx

Every crash can be explained.